# Add custom category in "Add a web part" section

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to create a new folder in the below category which will contain the custom web parts or App parts

[image: Add a web part]

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Did you find solution to this quetion for AppPart ?

Comment: No not yet. But what I had done is hided all the list and libraries of my apps in the "add an web part" section

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing custom web part, then you can do so. Just add following line in your `Element.xml`

```
<Property Name="Group" Value="{category name}" />
```

## Full code of my `Element.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="SpPlexSlider" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="SpPlexSlider\SpPlexSlider.webpart" Url="SpPlexWebPart_SpPlexSlider.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="SPPLEX" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

## Result I got

[image]

**PS:** Unfortunately, we can not categorize app parts!

Comment: Can we do this for sharepoint hosted app part ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option for add-ins!

Comment: Actually I want a solution for App part. Thank you for the response.